# Ui-component form (Adding drop down field)in magento 2

Tags: uicomponent, magento2.2.2, drop-downs, dependency, ui-form

I need to create backend admin form which contains two dropdown fields.But One is dependent on other. One dropdown contains attributes like brand,color etc.. The second one contains associate options of the attribute what you select in the first dropdown. If you select Brand, It should show all the available brands in second dropdown.

[image]

If you select color It would show all the available colors in the second dropdown
[image]

Is above scenario is possible in ui-component form in magento 2. Please suggest me, Am I need to create ui-component form or php form to do my task. Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi jaisa, Have you found any solution for that?

Comment: @krupaparikh, I done this using layout grid instead of using ui component. In layout grid you can add template for the specific field. If you have doubts let me know thanks

Comment: Do you know about how to update data in ui select dropdown?

Answer (score 1):

Please check example

https://github.com/Ximbo/magento2-dependent-fields

This example uses attributes **color** and **manufaturer** (as defined in di.xml).
Also it does not cover dataProvider usage and other things related to the ui component. Just about dependent selects.

Comment: Thanks for you reply,I will check and let u know