# How Do I create Backend form in magento 2 without using ui-component

Tags: adminform, magento2.2.2

I have created grid using ui-component, Now I want to create form without using ui-component. So please provide me a solution

Comment: Use block classes and XML .... Why would you not use ui-components?

Comment: Bcoz i have two drop down fields.one contains collection of attributes and the other one contains the collection of available options of associate attribute .

Comment: That is why I decided to use form without using ui component

Comment: Can you see this post then you will get a better understanding of what I need https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/216810/59735

Comment: You can add drop downs to UI Components, its good to use UI components whenever possible. Magento also recommends using it.

Answer (score 1):

For creating admin form without using ui-component download the sample extension from this [link](http://www.emiprotechnologies.com/technical_notes/magento-technical-notes-60/post/magento-2-sample-extension-for-beginners-318) and go through with it.