# How to create a custom UI Component dropdown field?

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, uicomponent, dropdown-attribute

Hi i'm new at magento 2 and i want to create a dropdown field with two custom strings options.
And if possible in other ocasion i would like to customize with a sql select values.

Comment: check this link --- https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/216810/ui-component-form-adding-drop-down-fieldin-magento-2